# Set input search readonly to false onclick

Tags: html, jquery

Clicking li will insert text to search field and making it in readonly at the same time.
How can I set the value to false when clicking on the input box? Thanks for your help.

```js
  $('#myid li').click(function(e) {
    $('#search').prop('readonly', true).val($(e.target).text());
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="search" id="search">
<ul id="myid">
  <li>text1</li>
  <li>text2</li>
</ul>
```

My use case: to prevent mobile keyboard showing when clicking the li.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thinks its straight forward. You can just use the click on the text field and set its `readyonly` to false

`$('#search').click(function(e) {
  $('#search').prop('readonly', false);
});`

```js
$('#myid li').click(function(e) {
    $('#search').prop('readonly', true).val($(e.target).text());
  });
  
$('#search').click(function(e) {
  $('#search').prop('readonly', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="search" id="search">
<ul id="myid">
  <li>text1</li>
  <li>text2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks Sir! it's really straight forward, I'm too much focused on changing the value within the same line. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can change `readonly` on input focus:

```js
$('#myid li').click(function(e) {
  $('#search').prop('readonly', true).val($(e.target).text());
});

// Add focus listener
$("#search").on("focus", function(e){
  $(this).prop('readonly', false);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="search" id="search">
<ul id="myid">
  <li>text1</li>
  <li>text2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks sir for ur answer, I tried but this one didnt work.